# Lyapunov function suggestion for a system

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory

Can you please suggest a Lyapunov function to prove the stability of the following system:

\begin{equation}
\dot x=-\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}-a \lambda - \lambda P u\\
\dot \lambda=(a+Pu)^\top x-b\\
\dot u=\lambda g(u) P^\top x
\end{equation}

where $a \in \mathbb{R}^n, P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, b \in \mathbb{R}, u \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, g(u)$ is a scalar function of $u$ and $f(x)$ is a scalar function of $x$.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Before looking at stability, you need to find an equilibrium point: you can then ask whether that equilibrium point is stable.  What is your equilibrium point?

Comment: I don't have an explicit form for the fixed point. I just know that norm of $u$ is equal to one at the fixed point.

Comment: So, one possible Lyapunov function would be $V(x)=\dot x^\top \dot x+\dot \lambda^\top \dot \lambda+(u^\top u-1)^2$. But I don't know how to prove the stability... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Assuming that b and u are inputs (otherwise this system is unstable), assuming also that the gradient of f yields 0 at 0. The origin is an equilibrium point. Then build a storage function for this equilibrium point, the last step is to find inputs b and u for which the Lie derivative is bounded by a negative definite function.

Comment: When we are at the origin. $\dot \lambda$ is not zero, so we can't say that origin is an equilibrium point. In fact, $a,b$ are two constant vectors and $P$ is a constant matrix in this system...

Answer (score 0):

Without further specification of $f$ and $g$, it will likely be impossible to determine if this is stable or not.

If $\nabla f$ is invertible and $g(0) = 0$, then $(x^*, \lambda^*,0)$ is an equilibrium point with $\lambda^*$ solving $a^{\sf T}[\nabla f]^{-1}(-a\lambda^{*}) = b$ and $x^*$ being recovered as $x^* = [\nabla f]^{-1}(-a\lambda^{*})$.

If you can determine some further properties of this equilibrium point (for example, via fixed point analysis), you may be able to perform a linear stability analysis.

Comment: What if $g(u)$ is an approximation of the sign function with $1-u^\top u$ in its argument. In other words, $g$ is 1 where $u^\top u<1$ and is 0 otherwise. Moreover, assume that $f$ be a convex function of $x$, for example $f(x)=x^\top Q x$. What can be said about system stability in terms of Lyapunov method? Thanks,